# Difference between GLS and SUR

Tags: regression, generalized-least-squares

I've been reading some about Generalized Least Squares (GLS) and trying to tie it back to my basic econometric background. I recall in grad school using Seemingly Unrelated Regression (SUR) which seems somewhat similar to GLS. One paper I stumbled on even referred to SUR as "special case" of GLS. But I still can't wrap my brain around the similarities and differences.

so the question:

What are the similarities and differences between GLS and SUR? What are the hallmarks of a problem which should use one method over the other?

Answer (score 9):

In a narrow sense, GLS (and in particular Feasible GLS or FGLS) is an estimation method applied to SUR models.

SUR implies a *system* of m equations that are assumed to have correlated errors, and (F)GLS helps to recover from this -- see [Wikipedia on Seemingly Unrelated Regressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seemingly_unrelated_regressions).

GLS, on the other hand, is a method of incorporating information from the covariance structure of your model.  See [Wikipedia on GLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feasible_generalized_least_squares).

To recap, you can use the latter (GLS) to estimate the former (SUR).

Comment: For illustration, here are some additional papers: http://j.mp/cBJ0hI, http://j.mp/deMrA8, http://j.mp/dhwcrv, http://j.mp/cyVx0m.